# sunspot solr complains bout unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

2.5 and ruby 2.1.6, with the latest version of sunspot_solr and sunspot_rails, when I run

```
rake sunspot:solr:run
```

it gives this error:

rake sunspot:solr:run
      Please require the stackprof gem falling back to fast_stack

```
  Starting Solr on port 8982 from /Users/nikso/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6@sync/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.3/solr/server

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/start/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I read a few posts and followed their suggestion of updating JAVA to the latest version 8 update 20, and JRE version 8 update 71, to no avail. Any anyone shed some light on this please?

Answer (score 1):

I addition to updating Java to latest version, I had to also set a correct path for JAVA_HOME environment variable.

In my case I edited ~/.bash_profile and added:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.i386/
```

Make sure the path matches the Java version you're running.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home` to find the home path, and `brew cask install java` to install latest java